# Mail smtp server configuration for PHP and RHEL

Tags: php, email, smtp

I'm running WordPress on an intranet VM and I need all outgoing messages to reach a remote smtp server.

In php.ini there is this specification:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
```

But my site is running on RHEL so where would I specify the SMTP server name?

Comment: IIRC PHP mail function uses sendmail command on UNIXes. Do you have sendmail command available? Sometimes it is missing if webserver/php is chrooted...

Comment: You're right. Sendmail is the way to go. Now configuring that is complicated. You have to create a copy of sendmail.cf using either makefile or m4. Not sure how this is going to work but I will post a new question.

Comment: sendmail doesn't need to be Sendmail. It can be even postfix which emulates sendmail binary feature...